# Need multiple views to respond to a touch event in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, first-responder

Setup:
I have two views that I need to respond to the touch event, and they are layered out on top of one another.
View 1 is on top of View 2.  View 2 is a UIWebView.  View 1 is sublclassed to capture the touch event.

My problem is that if I try to call the UIWebView event handlers (touchesBegan: and touchesEnded:) from within the event handlers of View 1, which is the first responder, nothing happens.  However if I set View 1 to userInteractionEnabled = NO, then the touch goes through that view and is processed properly by the 2nd view.

Any ideas on how I can have 2 views respond to a touch event?  Unfortunately the 2nd view is a UIWebView, so I need to actually call the event handler and not a different method, etc...

Thanks in advance for any advice,
Joel

Comment: The next thing I tried was to add a UIView above View1 and View 2, capture the touch event there, and then forward it on to each of the other views. View 1 responds just fine, but I can't get the UIWebView (View 2) to respond to the forwarded event.

Anyone have any ideas why the UIWebView doesn't want to play nice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to my problem. It's working on all kinds of UIView ! If someone whant to improve this code on the

```
catchUIEventTypeMotion default: ...
```

I hope that this code will be helpful for you.

```
PJ.
```

CustomWindow.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CustomWindow : UIWindow {
}

- (void) sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@end
```

CustomWindow.m

```
#import "CustomWindow.h"

@implementation CustomWindow

- (void) sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{       
    switch ([event type])
    {
        case UIEventTypeMotion:
            NSLog(@"UIEventTypeMotion");
            [self catchUIEventTypeMotion: event];
            break;

        case UIEventTypeTouches:
            NSLog(@"UIEventTypeTouches");
            [self catchUIEventTypeTouches: event];
            break;      

        default:
            break;
    }
    /*IMPORTANT*/[super sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event];/*IMPORTANT*/
}

- (void) catchUIEventTypeTouches: (UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in [event allTouches])
    {
        switch ([touch phase])
        {
            case UITouchPhaseBegan:
                NSLog(@"UITouchPhaseBegan");
                break;

            case UITouchPhaseMoved:
                NSLog(@"UITouchPhaseMoved");
                break;

            case UITouchPhaseEnded:
                NSLog(@"UITouchPhaseEnded");
                break;

            case UITouchPhaseStationary:
                NSLog(@"UITouchPhaseStationary");
                break;

            case UITouchPhaseCancelled:
                NSLog(@"UITouchPhaseCancelled");
                break;

            default:
                NSLog(@"iPhone touched");
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (void) catchUIEventTypeMotion: (UIEvent *)event
{
    switch ([event subtype]) {
        case UIEventSubtypeMotionShake:
            NSLog(@"UIEventSubtypeMotionShake");
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"iPhone in movement");
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomWindow.h"

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    CustomWindow *window;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet CustomWindow *window;

@end
```